# PHP: strototime last Sunday at 8 PM

Tags: php, strtotime

I need to get the Unix time stamp of the last sunday at 8 pm, so I tried:

```
strtotime("last sunday 8 pm");
```

This works great, but if it is `22-11-2015` at 9 PM for instance, the output is `15-11-2015 8 PM` instead of one hour ago. The method above works great except during the last four hours of sunday. How can I get `22-11-2015 8 PM`?

Comment: What timezone are you testing this in, and what do you have your php timezone set to?

Comment: UTC+1, but how is this relevant?

Comment: Because if you're checking at 9pm _local time_ and PHP believes it is in a different timezone than you, then it will correctly change its answer to your question when it becomes 8pm according to the timezone it is set to

Comment: In this case you are getting the correct answer. You are asking for 'last Sunday' which PHP is giving you. The answer you are expecting is __this__ Sunday.

Comment: @watcher: The server is in the same time zone I am in.

Comment: @vascowhite: I only want this sunday after 8 pm. Before 8 pm, last sunday is indeed what I want to have returned.

Comment: It doesn't matter where it is, it may matter what timezone it is configured for

Comment: @Rapti You can't expect PHP to know that, you will have to write custom code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper, but longer, way to complete this task

```
if((date('D',time()) == 'Sun') && (time() > strtotime('today 8 pm'))){ //if today is sunday and after 8pm, give todays date.
    $unix = strtotime('today 8 pm');
}
else{ //not sunday today, return last sunday.
    $unix = strtotime('last sunday');
}
```

Hacky/Original code:
You could check for "last sunday 8 pm" from tomorrows date.

```
strtotime('last sunday 8 pm', strtotime('tomorrow'));
```

Comment: And then what happens when you are checking last sunday 8pm on sunday at 7pm? I think that would give you the wrong answer

Comment: That really is a problem. Right now, `echo date("d.m.Y H:i:s", strtotime('last wednesday 11 pm', strtotime('tomorrow')));` returns `25-11-2015 23:00:00`. My local time is `25-11-2015 22:12:15`.

Comment: Ah. This bit of code is a little hacky, to be honest. As @vascowhite commented on your original post, you'll need to write custom code. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Found a solution. I used `+4 hours` instead of `tomorrow`. Thanks for giving me a hint in the right direction.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, I have updated my answer to include a proper way to do this, you can either use your solution and answer the question and mark as accepted, or use mine and mark it as accepted answer, just don't leave the question open! Thanks.